# Python, PIL and libtiff issue

Tags: python

When I do general PIL commands in Python, I get such an error message:

```
 >>> im.save('layer_86_.tiff')
TIFFSetField: layer_86_.tiff: Unknown tag 33922.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1685, in save
save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1185, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, 'libtiff', a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 430, in _getencoder
    return encoder(mode, *args + extra)
```

RuntimeError: Error setting from dictionary

I've seen at Github and SO similar questions, that date back to many years ago. But in my case this problem still can be reproduced. I've even installed libtiff.dll and put it in the System32 and SysWOW64 folders, but to no avail. So, how can I fix it?

This is another error message, that I see, when I try to rotate an image:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 100000000000
>>> img = Image.open('layer_71_.tiff')
>>> img.rotate(80,expand=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1603, in rotate
return self.transform((w, h), AFFINE, matrix, resample)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1862, in transform
im.__transformer((0, 0)+size, self, method, data, resample, fill)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1910, in __transformer

   image.load()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 245, in load
    if not self.map and (not LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES or t == 0) and e < 0:
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int()
```

So it seems like PIL does not work in many cases.

Comment: Did you install Pillow or PIL? Cause don't do the latter.